# How to test a function with jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I am making some test with jest in react native and I have remained in a function. If you have a solution about this function below, please write the response.
Thanks in advance!

```
resetPassOrCode() {

    this.setState({
        confirm: true
    });

    fetch(getResetPasswordUrl(), {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({resetCriteria: this.state.cd})
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 201) {
            Toast.show(LOGIN[this.state.language].EMAIL_SENT_SUCCESS)
        } else if (response.status === 404) {
            this.setState({
                confirm: false
            });
            Toast.show(LOGIN[this.state.language].USER_FOUND_ERROR)
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
            confirm: false
        });
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to test in the function ? What behavior ? Did you try something ? Paste the code of your `describe > test`, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: #c4k I am trying to reset the password. Here is the code of describe:
describe('Functions test', ()=> {
        beforeEach(() => {
            fetch.resetMocks()
        })
        it('should reset password or code', () => {
            const component = renderer.create(<LoginForm/>).getInstance();
            let data = component.resetPassOrCode()
            expect(data).toEqual("1111")
        })
    });

Comment: #c4k and gives me that error:

And gives me that error:
 fetch(getResetPasswordUrl(), {
          |         ^
      333 |             method: 'POST',
      334 |             headers: {
      335 |                 'Accept': 'application/json',

Comment: you need `jest-fetch-mock` module to mock fetch call.

Answer (score 0):

you can mock fetch as below:

```
var mockPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(<mock response data similar to actual promise response>);
});

fetch = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(mockPromise)
```